# Why SQL Server doesn't support foreign key constraints on views?

Tags: sql-server

I know that SQL Server doesn't support using a view as the reference for a foreign key constraint, is there a reason (i.e. something to do with the relational model) this is the case?  It seems like it would be useful....

Comment: I've asked a related question (not the why but how it could be done with other ways): [Are there DBMS that allow a Foreign Key that References a View (and not only base tables)?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/are-there-dbms-that-allow-a-foreign-key-that-references-a-view-and-not-only-bas) It probably has to do with the complexity of implementing such a feature. The relational model is fine with such a concept.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no fundamental problem with doing this, since tables and views are both relation variables in the relational model.  Foreign key constraints are just a particular subclass of general constraints, which standard SQL implements using `CREATE ASSERTION` so there's no particular SQL language difficulty either.

According to [this Connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/352700/foreign-key-references-view-column) (no longer available, and not archived) it's simply a matter of prioritization.  If you would find this feature useful, vote for the item and particularly add details of your use case in the comments.