# Can a PRIMARY KEY constraint (with a NONCLUSTERED INDEX) check for only certain values?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, nonclustered-index, check-constraints

Can I set a (logical) PRIMARY KEY constraint, served by a (physical) NONCLUSTERED INDEX, so that it only checks certain values of the constrained and indexed column **or** another column in the relevant table?

And, if so, can that column be established as a FOREIGN KEY constraint referenced from other tables?

I'm trying to basically see if I can remove certain rows from a *parent* table without removing those rows from a *child* table but still enforce the relationship for, e.g:

- `IDs > 1000`, or
- `CreatedDateTime > RemovalDate`.

For example, you can have that kind of constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable WITH NOCHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable CHECK (Id > 1000)
```

but how would you set this column as a PRIMARY KEY fixed with a NONCLUSTERED INDEX?

And can I do something like the following definition:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable WITH NOCHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable CHECK (CreatedOn > '01/01/2010')
```

but have an INDEX for the column named `Id`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion. The `CHECK (Id > 1000)` is **not** a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint, it is a `CHECK` constraint.

You can have a partial (filtered<sup>*</sup>) **unique** index, if that's what you are after: `UNIQUE (id) WHERE (id > 1000)`  (but this is not a primary key constraint or an index that can be used for the primary key constraint). Create it with:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Id_more_than_1000_PUQ
  ON MyTable (id) WHERE (id > 1000) ;
```

which means that all `id` values that are bigger than 1000 will appear only once on that column. All other values (1000 and lower) will be allowed as duplicates.

And similarly for the date column:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Id_when_created_on_2010_and_after_PUQ
  ON MyTable (id) WHERE (CreatedOn >= '20100101') ;
```

which means that for rows that have `CratedOn` on 2010 and afterwards, the `id` values will be unique. All other rows (that have `CreatedOn` at 2009 and earlier or `NULL`) will be ignored for that unique index. So you may have duplicate `id` values as long as all but one do not match the `WHERE` condition of the index.

These indexes will be non-clustered of course - all partial indexes are.
And they cannot be used as targets for `FOREIGN KEY` constraints.

*: See the [`CREATE INDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) and [Fileterd indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) pages on MSDN or details of use and advantages.

---

About they "why can't we reference a partial index?":

This is what the SQL standard says and how it's implemented in SQL Server. An FK constraint has to reference a column (or columns) of a table. Not an index. A partial index by definition holds a part of the values that appear in the column, not all of them.

A related question I asked some time ago: [Are there DBMS that allow a Foreign Key that References a View (and not only base tables)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/are-there-dbms-that-allow-a-foreign-key-that-references-a-view-and-not-only-bas).

There is no inherent problem in the relational model that would disallow such FKs to be defined. But the SQL (committee and the various DBMS) have not added this as a feature.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot have a Primary Key that only works for some of the rows. It would really cease being a Primary key at that point. Emphasis on Primary.

You can play with [filtered indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for a Unique index and that filter can be on values you specify.

But a primary key is there to enforce uniqueness so you can't make only some of the table part of the key.

You can disable the FKs while you make fixes, you can build a foreign key relationship on an existing table with `NOCHECK` - but that will mean that none of the relationships are checked. You have an untrusted foreign key and some of the benefits foreign keys offer like foreign key join elimination can't work that way because SQL isn't guaranteed that your row is there or not there.

Alternatively you could just not define that relationship and deal with the ramifications. But you are basically asking SQL server to break the referential integrity at the outset by making exceptions. If you could cart those exceptions off into a separate table and join to that table in a view or something like that you could get around this and keep the relationship on the "real" table moving forward.

Remember though: A filtered index just can give you some uniqueness on the other side of filter. This doesn't address FKs or even the PK. I think a better answer is fix the issue with the data. Even a -1 primary key value for "unknown" as is common in warehouses would be better than orphans.